# Use CSV in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops

We are trying to set up an infrastructure pipeline in Azure DevOps and we have a requirement to have several variables set with each infra build, which will be defined by the project. This also involves copying VMs from one location to another and renaming etc. I can do this through Powershell, however I'm struggling on how to import all the variables for each infra build. Since there are a few I was thinking I could use an Excel file (csv) and then do a foreach loop, that way the code is consistent and simpler.

Is there a way to have a CSV uploaded to Azure DevOps that triggers the powershell pipeline to run or is there even a way I can add a CSV to a pipeline, I can always look at another trigger once the CSV has been uploaded?

There are 7 fields (columns) in each infra build and there could be up to 30-50 builds (rows) running at each time hence the desire to automate it and use a CSV, adding variables each time is just not practical.

Thanks in advance and hope that makes snese

Thanks

Comment: May I know how the pipeline is reading the input paramaters from the csv file?

Comment: @Vowneee hi I use a powershell script which calls the Csc file, the Csc must be in a folder at root called “csv” hope that helps.

Comment: could you please help me with sample code how you achieved this. I am looking for a bash script for the same as my build agents are linux

Comment: @Vowneee could you let me know if you still need some help, sorry been away for Xmas and new year 

Comment: How this an be achieved in shel script. where all the variables for the pipeline should be picked from csv file columns . Raws for multiple items..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have a CSV uploaded to Azure DevOps that triggers
> the powershell pipeline to run or is there even a way I can add a CSV
> to a pipeline, I can always look at another trigger once the CSV has
> been uploaded?

From this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#wildcards), the * can only set as the final character.

So, you can create a folder named 'csv' to upload the '.csv' file, then set your yml  file like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - 'csv/*'
```

Comment: thanks for that, just another quick one, how would I reference that in the powershell script as path ? 